# Laravel echo is no listening

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-echo

I'm trying to do a simple real time chat using broadcast events with socket.io

That is my chatController..

```php
public function index(Request $request) {
      $sender=Auth::user()->id;
      $receiver=\App\User::find(2);
      $message=new Message;
      $message->message="Hola, esto es una prueba de eventos";
      $message->user_receiver_id=$receiver->id;
      $message->user_sender_id=Auth::user()->id;
      $message->id_chat=1;
      $message->save();

      event(new \App\Events\sendMessage($message,$receiver));

      return response()->json(["status"=>"ok"]);
}
```

This chat store in a database the messages according to determinate group (chat).

The event that will be fired is:

```php
class sendMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $message;
    public $user_receiver;

    public function __construct(Message $message,User $user_receiver)
    {
        $this->message=$message;
        $this->user_receiver=$user_receiver;

    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        \Log::info($this->message->id_chat);

        return new PrivateChannel('chat.1');


    }
}
```

My app.js is:

```js
require('./bootstrap');
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});


window.Echo.channel('chat.1')
    .listen('sendMessage', e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

To start, I just want to get the public variables from my `sendMessages` event; after this I will build the view.

I've run `php artisan listener` and the Laravel echo server. But when I send a message I get this output on the server:

```
CHANNEL private-chat.1
CHANNEL private-chat.1
CHANNEL private-chat.1
```

And this on the client:

```
$ php artisan queue: listen
[2017-05-11 23:26:42] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:26:43] Processed: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:29:28] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:29:291 Processed: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:32:11] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:32:12] Processed: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:46:46] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:46:47] Processed: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:50:32] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:50:33] Processed: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:50:52] Processing: App\Events\sendMessage
[2017-05-11 23:50:53] Processed: App \Events\sendMessage
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
The process "'/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' queue:work 11 --once --queue='default ' --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.
```

Answer (score 32):

If you using the Echo.channel(`my-channel`) for example you need to do something like this, attention to the ('.my-event') for some reason you need to a (.) before the event name.

```
Echo.channel(`my-channel`)
.listen('.my-event', (e) => {
    consolec.log(e);
});
```

Comment: This is why you need to add (.) as your event prefix: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#broadcast-name

Answer (score 4):

I hope someone find this helpful, also faced a lot of hours to fix echo to listen to
my events and here's how I've solved it. I'm using Laravel 7 and pusher server 4.0

see: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites

MyEvent.php

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('my-channel');
}

public function broadcastAs()
{
    return 'my-event';
}
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

 window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

 window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     encrypted:true,
     forceTLS: true
 });
```

resources/views/your_views.blade.php

```
Echo.channel(`my-channel`)
.listen('.my-event', (e) => {
    console.log('Test');
});
```

Note: If you declare broadcastAs() make sure in your .listen() formatted like the above code.

Note: Make sure to run "npm run dev" everytime you have changes in app.js or bootstrap.js file.

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `use SerializesModels;`

Also, `broadcast(new \App\Events\sendMessage($message,$receiver));`

You can find Laravel 5 Broadcasting example here,

https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/real-time-application

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am using Redis I noticed that there is a prefix for my channel name projectName_database, Laravel> 5.7 automatically adds a prefix to your channel name, you can delete the prefix in config / database.php
Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You are broadcasting in Laravel on a PrivateChannel so you need to use the following when connecting with Echo:

```
window.Echo.private('chat.1').listen('sendMessage', e => {console.log(e);});
```

If you're still having problems then have a look at this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807743/2867894)

Answer (score -1):

Check the version of "socket.io-client", you need to use 2.x instead of 3.x