# Vue Laravel Echo not listening to channel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I am using `laravel-echo` to listen to my laravel WebSocket channel.

I added this to my `app.js`:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

/*..........*/

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js')

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'appKey',
  wsHost: window.location.hostname,
  wsPort: 6001,
  forceTLS: false,
  disableStats: true
})
```

I have an event called `WebsocketMeasurements`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
Use App\Measurement;

class WebsocketMeasurements implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $measurement;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Measurement $measurement)
    {
        $this->measurement = $measurement;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel ('measurement.created');
    }
}
```

And I added this to my `dashboard.vue` file:

```
mounted () {
    window.Echo.channel('measurement.created').listen('WebsocketMeasurements', (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  },
```

When I try to fire an test event at /laravel-websockets nothing happens. I fill in the following data:
Channel: `measurement.created`
Event: ``` WebsocketMeasurements`` Data: ``` {"data": null}`

What I expected to happen is to receive `{"data": null}` in the console, but there's nothing logged there.

The vent does show up in the events list at laravel-websockets as an api-message with the following details:
`Channel: measurement.created, Event: WebsocketMeasurements`

I also tried making `Channel` a `PrivateChannel` and changing `window.Echo.channel` to `window.Echo.private` in my dashboard vue, this resulted in a 403 error to the link /broadcaster/auth.

Before I started I did the following commands in the terminal:
`php artisan serve`
`npm run hot`
`php artisan queue:work`
`php artisan websockets:serve`
`php artisan queue:listen`

I also tried running `npm run watch` instead of hot, this didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel echo is no listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927792/laravel-echo-is-no-listening)

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks for the fast reply. They are all using the normal `blade.php` files, I am not using this. I'm using the following: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa
All my pages are vue components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing

```
window.Echo.channel('measurement.created').listen('.WebsocketMeasurements', (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      this.websockets.push(e)
    })
```

with

```
Echo.channel('measurement.created').listen('.WebsocketMeasurements', (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      this.websockets.push(e)
    })
```