# Laravel Echo + Redis + Socket.io

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

**Laravel 5.6**

I am trying to create a Real Time App. I followed the tutorial found in google but then it seems like it doesn't work. I can't figure out why because it doesn't show error in console.

in **config/app.php**

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

this is my Event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;


class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $message;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Message $message)
{
     $this->message = $message;
     // $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    //
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('chat-channel');
}
}
```

Here's my **controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use App\Events\MessageSent;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('chat');
}

public function getChat()
{
    return Message::with('user')->get();
}

public function addChat()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $message = $user->messages()->create(['message' => request('message')]);

    event(new MessageSent($message));

    return $message->toJson();



}
}
```

at the bottom of my **bootstrap.js**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.io = require('socket.io-client');
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

my **laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
"authHost": "http://localhost",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "1461f99e6c0bcaa4",
        "key": "3dc5701da38d9c3346141db0c8e3f0ad"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": null,
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": "",
"sslCertChainPath": "",
"sslPassphrase": "",
"apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
}
}
```

my **ChatComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Chatroom</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="chat-log" v-for="message in messages">
                        <strong>{{message.user.name}}</strong>
                        <br>
                        - {{message.message}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center" v-show="messages.length === 0">
                        No messages yet!
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card-footer">
                    <div class="chat-composer">
                        <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Start typing..." v-model="messageText"         
@keydown.enter="sendMessage()">
                        &nbsp;
                        &nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"             
@click="sendMessage()">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
        this.getMessages();
        this.listen();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            messages: [],
            messageText: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getMessages() {
            axios.get('/getChat').then((response) => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },
        sendMessage() {
            let data = {
                message: this.messageText,
                user: {
                    name: $('#navbarDropdown').text()
                }
            }

            axios.post('/sendChat', data).then((response) => {
                this.messages.push(data);
                this.messageText = '';
            });
        }, 
        listen() {
            Echo.channel('chat-channel').listen('.MessageSent', (message) => 
{
                this.messages.push(message);
                // console.log(message);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.chat-composer {
    display: flex;
}
</style>
```

if someone knows the solution to this one. Please help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think there few things that you've miss.

If your setup like this Redis + Laravel Echo Server + Socket.io, then you can try this.

1. Update `BROADCAST_DRIVER, QUEUE_DRIVER, QUEUE_CONNECTION` on `.env` file to redis. Run `redis-server`, and `artisan queue:listen --tries=1` and also `laravel-echo-server start`
2. On your Event class, there's no data you want to sent/broadcast. Try add `broadcastWith` method and simply return whatever data you want inside that method. You can read on Laravel official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#broadcast-data

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to remove the '.' from the beginning of the event name 'MessageSent':

```
Echo.channel('chat-channel').listen('MessageSent', (message) => ...
```

Also you can check out this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60807743/2867894)